# Aligning two divs beneath each other? rails

Tags: css, alignment, erb

I have these two button divs which I want to align right under each other, with some 10px margin between each other. Here is the code, no point with claptrap.

```
<div id = "buttons">

      <div id = "signin-button">
      <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path, :id => "SignInText" %>
    </div>

    <div id = "signup-button">
      <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, :id => "SignUpText" %>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Don't forget that IDs are supposed to be unique. Instead use a class.

Comment: I still feel like my buttons are unique? Why a class?

Comment: @RickKuipers The first one is "sign **in**", the second one is "sign **up**"

Comment: My bad, read it wrong :P

Comment: No hard feelings mate! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some css and you done:

```
#signin-button,
#signup-button
{
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

And change your divs to use class instead of id.

Comment: This worked smoothly! :) 
Aren't the buttons which've been specified with ids quite unique?

Comment: Oops :) It looked like their ids are same. Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The two divs can be aligned beneath each other with this css -

```
 #signin-button,#signup-button{ display : inline position:absolute;margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Comment: Morpheus's solution worked great, but thanks for helping either way. If I run into problems, I will try this out :=D